# useEffect sendo chamado mais de uma vez

Tags: javascript, react, websocket

Estou criando uma pequena aplicação de chat em tempo real utilizando websockets, porém o useEffect está sendo chamado 2 vezes, e retornando para o usuário a mensagem duplicada, como posso estar resolvendo isso? Segue o código abaixo.

````
const Chat = ({ socket }) => {

    const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
    const [messageList, setMessageList] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        socket.on('receiveMessage', (data) => {
            setMessageList((list) => [...list, data])
        })

        console.log('chamou')

    },[socket])

    function sendMessage(){
        if(message.trim() === '') return;

        socket.emit('message', {message})
        setMessage('');
        clearInput();
    }

    function clearInput(){
        document.querySelector('#input').value = '';
    }

    return ( 
        <div className='chat-container'>
            <div className='chat-header'>
                <h1>Chat</h1>
            </div>

            <div className='chat-body'>
                { messageList.map((data) => (
                    <p>{ data.message }</p>
                ))}
            </div>

            <div className='chat-footer'>
                <input id='input' type="text" onChange={e=> setMessage(e.target.value)}/>
                <button onClick={() => sendMessage()}>Enviar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
     );
}
 
export default Chat;```
````

Comment: Onde este componente é inicializado?

Answer (score -2):

Agora com a versão 18 do React, ao usar o Strict Mode, sempre que um componente for montado, o React simulará a desmontagem e a remotagem do componente. E isso só acontece no momento do desenvolvimento. Caso não queira esse comportamento, então pode remover o Strict Mode. Para saber mais, segue o link da própria do React documentação, que fala sobre isso: https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#ensuring-reusable-state

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).